# How to do a reverse operation to tf.nn.embedding_lookup?

Tags: python, tensorflow, word-embedding

I have an `embedded_chars` array, created with this code:

```
self.input_x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, sequence_length], name="input_x")

W = tf.Variable( 
    tf.random_uniform([vocab_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0),
    name="W"
    )
self.embedded_chars = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(W, self.input_x)
```

I want get `input_x` array if I have only `embedded_chars` and `W`.

How can I get it?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this conceptually possible? The forward lookup is one-to-one mapping. Is the reversed function also a one-to-one mapping>

Answer (score 5):

You can use the cosine distance between the embedding vectors in `W` and `embedded_chars`:

```
# assume embedded_chars.shape == (batch_size, embedding_size)
emb_distances = tf.matmul( # shape == (vocab_size, batch_size)
    tf.nn.l2_normalize(W, dim=1),
    tf.nn.l2_normalize(embedded_chars, dim=1),
    transpose_b=True)
token_ids = tf.argmax(emb_distances, axis=0) # shape == (batch_size)
```

Here `emb_distances` is a dot product of the L2-normalized matrices `W` and `transpose(embedded_chars)`, which is the same as cosine distance between all the vectors in `W` and all the vectors in `embedded_chars`. The argmax simply gives us the index of the highest value in each column of `emb_distances`.

@Yao Zhang: If all embeddings in `W` are different, as they should be, then this will give you the correct result: cosine distance is always between [-1, 1] and cos(vector_a, vector_a) == 1.

Note that often you shouldn't need to do this kind of conversion from embedding to token index: usually you can directly take the value of the tensor that is passed as the second argument to `tf.nn.embedding_embedding_lookup`, which is a tensor of token indices.